# How to drop a schema automatically?I want the program to work in a way where it checks if schema exists then drop the schema and recreate it

Tags: xml, jpa

How to drop a schema automatically in JPA?I want the program to work in a way where it checks if schema exists then drop the schema and recreate it.In persistance.xml I have provided the property
.
And nowhere I am creating a SCHEMA ,But I am not able to drop the schema.May I know what could be the solution?

Comment: with hibernate you can use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop

Answer (score 0):

In JPA 2.1, you can use this property:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
              value="drop-and-create"/>
```

The possible values for this property are:

- none: No schema creation or deletion will take place.
- create: The provider will create the database artifacts on application deployment. The artifacts will remain unchanged after application redeployment
- drop-and-create: Any artifacts in the database will be deleted, and the provider will create the database artifacts on deployment.
- drop: Any artifacts in the database will be deleted on application deployment.

Comment: I have already added the above mentioned property ,it has no effect.